# setTimeout inside component is getting called regardless of componentWillUnmount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have used setInterval to fetch the data which will be invoked every 30secs. Below is the snippet of that.

```
this.interval = setInterval(() => this.props.fetchEvents().catch((err) => {
   this.setState({ isLoadingFailed: true });
}), 30000);
```

Now i am implementing sorting functionality in which my component will be re-rendered when i click sort button.
So when my component is re-rendered i am trying to destroy the call sent for fetching the data by implementing 'componentWillUnmount' but it is not working and my sorting is done only after data is fetched.

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  clearInterval(this.interval);
}
```

Sorting:

```
changeSortOrder() {
  if (this.state.inAsc == -1) {
    this.state.inAsc = 1;
  } else {
    this.state.inAsc = -1;
  }
}
```

Sorting button html:

```
{
    this.state.group == 'admin' && this.state.inAsc == -1
      ? <Tooltip content="Click to Sort" position={Position.BOTTOM}>
        <span className="event-main-navigation-element" onClick={this.changeSortOrder.bind(this)}>
          <SortAsc className="event-main-navigation-icon" />
        </span>
      </Tooltip>
      : this.state.group == 'admin' && this.state.inAsc == 1 
      ? <Tooltip content="Click to Sort" position={Position.BOTTOM}>
      <span className="event-main-navigation-element" onClick={this.changeSortOrder.bind(this)}>
        <SortDesc className="event-main-navigation-icon" />
      </span>
    </Tooltip> : <div />
}
```

Can someone let me know how i can destroy the call?

Comment: Problem is not the interval, most likely it is the this.props.fetchEvents() running asynchronously. So fetchEvents probably need a check.

Comment: Where are you setting the interval?

Comment: @epascarello this.props.fetchEvents() is running asynchronously.

Comment: @SLaks i am not setting it anywhere. Just using it to for fetching the data.

Comment: `cWU` seems inappropriate; it's not going to be unmounted just because you're fetching data. I'm not sure what you're actually trying to do--stop fetching data once it's been sorted? Clear the interval when you sort. Or set a flag and check whether or not you need to re-load the data. Noting that a 30-sec frame might be a curious UX if the data changes a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`componentWillUnmount()` is only called when a component is removed from the DOM, as mentioned in [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html?utm_source=caibaojian.com#componentwillunmount):

> componentWillUnmount() is invoked immediately before a component is unmounted and destroyed.

So your `clearInterval()` is not called on clicking the button. You could clear the interval in the `changeSortOrder()` call.

On a side-note:

> Constructor is the only place where you should assign this.state directly. In all other methods, you need to use this.setState() instead.
>   (see [constructor docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html?utm_source=caibaojian.com#constructor))